# connection failed for: myhost (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Jun C) error with capistrno

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

Running command cap deploy:setup under my application root, after entering the password for remote web server, there is an error:

```
connection failed for: myhost (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Jun C)
```

I log in to the remote web server through VPN and ssh.

Here is the deploy.rb:

```
set :application, "myapp"
set :repository,  "git://github.com/myapp/myapp.git"
set :deploy_to, "/vol/www/apps/#{application}"

set :scm, :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

server "remote server ip", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
```

Any thoughts about the error? Thanks.

Comment: Do you log into your remote server using the same username as your development machine? From the capistrano wiki:

`set :user, “foo”` _If you log into your server with a different user name than you are logged into your local machine with, you’ll need to tell Capistrano about that user name._

Comment: I found the link below helps for deploy.rb configuration:  http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/